# Android Layout, view height is equal to screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

in Android how to make a view have same height as its screen size, is it possible to achieve this with only the xml? or if it must use script, tell me how

Thanks.

---

Sorry for being not clear, and thanks for your reply

but i think, match_parent and fill_parent attribute is not reliable, because when i put the view inside one container or change the view container hierarchy, it won't work.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/2KJYdDM5) my complete xml layout.

The element i want to make the height sam with device screen is the last list view inside relative layout

[image]

Comment: Remove the padding attribute of the parent Layout and make the height and width of your view to "MATCH_PARENT"

Answer (score 3):

**No you cannot achieve this in XML only.**

As Android supports multiple screen sizes, at runtime you need to check for each device size. The height for each device can be calculated like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;
```

With the above code, you will get the height of the screen and you need to set this height in **dp** to your view at runtime.

Do this in your activity:

```
// get view you want to resize
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

// get layout parameters for that view
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mainLayout.getLayoutParams();

// change height of the params e.g. 480dp
params.height = 480;

// initialize new parameters for my element
mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(params));
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible from `xml layout`. To do this make the parent layout height and width `fill_parent or match_parent` and then set each child view width `fill_parent or match_parent.` Don't set any `padding or margin` to parent layout. Hope it will work. Here I am giving you an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_swap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left or Right" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/my_surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Attention:** If you use `ScrollView`, you have to set `fillViewport="true"` otherwise it will not work. A Google engineer said about it before. Check it from [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Display screenDisplay = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
LayoutHeight = screenDisplay.getHeight();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutHeight, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
view.setLayoutParams(listLayoutParams);
```