# Android: How to add Image and then text below it in scroll view?

Tags: android, scrollview

Hi guys I am trying to build a layout but I am not able to understand how to build it 
what I am trying to do is to add a Image whose height and width will be of screen size and below it will be a description about the Image which the users can view when they scroll it but the whole screen will be consisting of image only until the user scrolls the text below will not be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"

    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/relativla"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"

        android:background="@drawable/hamburger"
        android:id="@+id/navi"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/descrpitiondietplan"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
         />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

you can see in the below link the way i want the layout to be

http://postimg.org/image/avgmk6pi3/

please feel free to drop in comments if you need any additional details

**EDIT 1**

After trying rachel solution I am getting this

http://postimg.org/image/tdb02gu9l/

now as you can see in the image the image view is taking whole width of the screen which is fine but it doesn't take the whole height of the screen if i write match_parent to the imageview layout_height the image takes the whole screen but it doesn't allow me to scroll

Comment: Your description is different than your sample image.  You say you want the image to be the width and height of the screen, but your sample shows the image is only the width of the screen, and the text is taking up the rest of the space below it.  Also I'm not clear at all about how you want text to scroll.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sir the image over their will rake the size of the screen so the first thing when you open the app you will see the image and after that you can scroll down and read the text about that image

Comment: @DougStevenson I hope now i am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working after a bit of research on google and stackoverflow finally got a way

so here it is first your activity / fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);


        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dp);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        float scalingFactor = this.getBitmapScalingFactor(bitmap);

        Bitmap newBitmap = Util.ScaleBitmap(bitmap, scalingFactor);

        // Set the bitmap as the ImageView source
        this.img.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);

        return v;
    }
    private float getBitmapScalingFactor(Bitmap bm) {
        // Get display width from device
        int displayWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        // Get margin to use it for calculating to max width of the ImageView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.img.getLayoutParams();
        int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
        int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;

        // Calculate the max width of the imageView
        int imageViewWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);

        // Calculate scaling factor and return it
        return ( (float) imageViewWidth / (float) bm.getWidth() );
    }
```

as i am using fragment I have onCreateView onCreate will be for people using activity

and create a Utils class

```
public class Util {
    public static Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, float scalingFactor) {
        int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scalingFactor);
        int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scalingFactor);

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
    }
```

if you guys have a better solution do let me know

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to do some work to get the screen size of the device, then set the image view's size programatically using that.

See the accepted answer here for more details on calculating the device screen size: [Android Layout, view height is equal to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805981/android-layout-view-height-is-equal-to-screen-size)

Comment: Sure rachel I will try it and let you know

Comment: Updated please take a look